# Use of "indes" in the meaning of "jedoch"

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Ich würde gerne fragen, ob *indes* (oder *indessen*) auch als Synonym für *jedoch* verwendet werden kann. 
Ich weiß, dass *indes* nicht so häufig ist, und dass es auch im Sinne von *mittlerweile* oder *während* verwendet werden kann. Ich habe aber gehört, dass man es auch im Sinne wie *jedoch* verwendet. Ist das möglich? Könnt ihr mir einige Beispiele schreiben?

Comment: _Die Frage gefällt mir; indes – auf dem "wahrend" fehlen die Umlaut-Pünktchen._ Ja, "indes" bedeutet "jedoch", aber es wird in der üblichen Umgangssprache selten verwendet. Es erregt stets Aufmerksamkeit, weil es so ungewöhnlich ist. Falls Du das beabsichtigst, ist "indes" ein schönes Wort.

Comment: Danke, ich weiß schon, hatte nur keine Lust die Sprache meiner Tastatur zu ändern :) Also während. 
Ich finde indes auch ein schönes Wort. Kannst du aber einen Beispielsart sagen, wo indes im Sinne als "jedoch" und nicht "während" steht?

Comment: Ich dachte, mein einleitender _kursiv_ gesetzter Satz im ersten Kommentar sei ein solches Beispiel. _Indes: Ich habe mich wohl geirrt._

Comment: Ich verstehe schon, habe gar nicht bemerkt. :D
Danke schön, mir kommt das jetzt noch so unnatürlich vor, dass ich das Wort auch beim Lesen ignoriere. Aber ich sehe schon den zweiten Satz auch. Interessant.

Comment: Warum schaust du nicht in ein Wörterbuch? Dort wird das ausführlich und mit anschaulichen Beispielen erklärt. Z.B. im Grimmschen Wörterbuch http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GI00336#XGI00336 oder im Duden http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/indessen_waehrend_wohingegen

Comment: Das habe ich gemacht, ich wollte nur wissen, ob man das Wort in Deutschland benutzt, aber ich habe meine Antwort schon von PerlDuck bekommen. Danke für die Tipps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ich weiß, dass *indes* (...) auch im Sinne von *mittlerweile* oder *während* verwendet werden kann. Ich habe aber gehört, dass man es auch im Sinne wie jedoch verwendet. Ist das möglich?

Ich würde diese Fragestellung andersherum angehen: Das Wort *indes* ist ungefähr gleichbedeutend mit *während*. *Während* kann normalerweise auch verwendet werden, um einen Gegensatz oder Widerspruch ausdrücken. Dies trifft eigentlich auch auf alle anderen Formulierungen für Gleichzeitigkeit (*zur selben Zeit*, *zur gleichen Zeit*, *zeitgleich*, *währenddessen*) zu - somit auch auf *indes*.

Answer (score 3):

Eine wunderschöne Sammlung von Zitaten mit Verwendung von [indes/indessen](http://dwds.de/wb/indes) in der Bedeutung von *aber, jedoch* und in der Bedeutung von *unterdessen, inzwischen* findet man im DWDS:

- [DWDS-Kernkorpus](http://dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=%7Bindes,indessen%7D)

  > - *Das behielt sich indes Hawa vor, und der wollte keine Begleitung dorthin, was ihm ausgeredet werden konnte.*
  > - *Zur Befragung zählebiger Klischees über deutsche Tugenden und Sünden laden sie indes ausdrücklich ein.*
- [DWDS Die Zeit](http://dwds.de/r?corpus=zeit;q=%7Bindes,indessen%7D)

  > - *Österreichs Innenministerin Johanna Mikl-Leitner forderte in der Welt am Sonntag indes weitere Grenzschließungen.*
  > - *Die Deutschen scheinen sich indes damit abzufinden, dass es auch hierzulande zu einem Anschlag kommen könnte.*

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man *indes* im Sinne von *jedoch* verwendet, ist die Satzstellung meist eine andere.
Mit *indes* wird eine gewisse Spannung erzeugt, weil das Wort nicht sehr geläufig ist
und daher Aufmerksamkeit erregt. Bei jedoch ist das nicht ganz so:

> Ich habe mir eine Jeans gekauft, jedoch keine Blaue.

Hier ist *jedoch* Synonym zu *aber*.

> Ich habe mir eine Jeans gekauft, aber keine Blaue.

Kein Unterschied.

Wenn Du hingegegen *indes* verwendest, würdest Du eher schreiben:

> Ich habe mir eine Jeans gekauft, indes: sie ist nicht blau.

Es sind eigentlich zwei Sätze, die durch das *indes* miteinander verbunden sind. Etwas salopp könnte man *indes* umschreiben mit *jedoch (Überraschung!)*, wie in

> Ich habe mir eine Jeans gekauft, jedoch (Überraschung!): sie ist nicht blau.

Comment: I've been reading German newspapers for nearly three years now and I cannot remember seeing a colon after indes.

Comment: I found a sentence with indes in it  in a newspaper, that's why I asked :)